# Infer type derived from other type

Tags: typescript

I want to create a generic function which has a generic string union parameter which in turn defines an object parameter where the name of the property depends on the generic parameter.

Imagine this example, where `params` is either `{customerId: 'some string'}` or `{supplierId: 'some string'}`, and I want to infer `T` from `params` so that if a `customerId` is supplied, the function is called as `foo<'customer'>`:

```
type Type = 'customer' | 'supplier'
type EncodedType<T extends Type> = `${T}Id`;

// needs to be a mapped type to not become Record<'customerId' | 'supplierId', string>, 
// i.e., with both properties always present
type Params<T extends Type> = {
  [P in T]: Record<EncodedType<P>, string>;
}[T]; 

function foo<T extends Type>(params: Params<T>) {
}
```

However, when calling this as `foo({customerId: '42'})`, `T` is inferred to `Type`, not to `customer`.
If I manually do `foo<'customer'>({customerId: '42})`, then `params` is validated to fulfill `Params<'customer'>`, but if I don't explicitly specify `T`, it's not inferred from the passed object, but simply left as `Type`.

I know that if I turn this around and have two generic parameters, it works:

```
type DecodedType<T extends EncodedType<Type>> = T extends `${infer P}Id` ? P : never;

function foo2<K extends EncodedType<Type>, T extends DecodedType<K>>(params: Record<K, string>) {
}

foo2({customerId: '42'}) // called as foo2<'customerId', 'customer'>
```

... because apparently TypeScript can infer `K` from the record, and then in turn infer `T` from `K` - but it cannot seem to infer a transformed type from the keys of a record as in the first example.

I'd like to keep the function clean with only one generic type. Is it possible to create the function so that it takes `<T extends Type>` and infers `T` from the `params` object?

Edit: I realize that my example was too dumbed down, so I'll make another (albeit silly) example:

```
type Type = 'foo' | 'bar';
type Params<T extends Type> = {
  foo: {a: number};
  bar: {b: number};
}[T];

declare function func<T extends Type>(params: Params<T>): Uppercase<T>;

const result = func({a: 42});
```

here, `T` will not be inferred into `'foo'` or `'bar'`, respectively, from the name of the key in `params`. Instead `T` will stay as `'foo' | 'bar'`. This means that `result` as returned from the call to `func` will be of type `'FOO' | 'BAR'` instead of just `'FOO'`.

I do also realize that it's nothing really *wrong* with the code for `foo2` above, it just bugs me that it doesn't seem possible to infer a type `T` with the value `'customer'` from an object parameter by examining that it has a key called `customerId`; only vice versa - deriving the key name `customerId` from the generic parameter `customer`.

Comment: Why do you need `T` at all in your second function?  There should be one type parameter, and that's `K`.  Then you can use `EncodedType<K>` anywhere you would normally need `T`.  Since presumably you already knew that, could you [edit] to demonstrate a situation where it wouldn't work for you to use `K` instead of `T`?

Comment: I realize that it's not clear from the example, but I do need `T` for the return type, which I left out here for simplicity.

Comment: Another silly example, illustrating that I want to pass params which are derived from T and hence infer T from it

`type Type = 'foo' | 'bar'; type Params<T extends Type> = {
  foo: {a: number};
  bar: {b: number};
}[T];

declare function func<T extends Type>(params: Params<T>): Uppercase<T>;

const result = func({a: 42});`

Here, `result` is `'FOO' | 'BAR'`, not `'FOO'`. :(

Comment: But you don't need it for the return type, you can just use `EncodedType<K>` instead of `T`, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NaLXpw).  Please, though, [edit] the example to demonstrate what you need, since otherwise it's *too* minimal to be a [mre].  .... please edit your code in the question, as opposed to putting code in the comments.

Comment: Yeah, I guess I can write my code the other way around, and yes, I can even use `EncodedType<K>` everywhere, but I was curious if I could write cleaner code by turning it all around, effectively having `T` inferred from `K` instead of the other way around.

Comment: If it doesn't work that way, then apparently you can't.  You would be making the code "cleaner" but the job for the inference algorithm much dirtier.  Inferring `T` from `\`${T}Id\`` is much harder than inferring `K` from `K`.

Comment: I edited the question to add some more context. To explain further, in my real code, there are 3 sets of parameters, and with the more verbose solution I ended up having to use 6 generic parameters for my functions, which just made the code unbearably ugly.

Comment: If it's not possible, fair enough. I didn't think it was, but I thought I'd give it a try since there are countless times where I've concluded that something isn't possible, and then I've got some brilliant suggestion from here (usually from you, @jcalz )

Comment: So how would you like to proceed here? I could write up an answer saying that inference won't work in the direction you're trying to do it (things like [ms/TS#49839](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/49839) are what happens when you try it) and that you can write `foo2` with just `K` and compute `T`, or continue using both `K` and `T`, but there's currently no magic bullet for this.  Does that fully address the question or am I missing something?

Comment: That issue seems to describe it fairly well. Heck, when seeing it, I do understand why that infer operation is complex. Trying to infer parts of a string literal type could become a nightmare. I'd be happy to accept an answer with a reference to that issue with a short explanation that this is just out of scope for the infer algorithm. Thanks!

Comment: Okay I'll do so when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `foo2()` function works because you are asking the compiler to infer the [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type `K` from a value of type `Record<K, string>`, which is fairly straightforward (it's basically just the same as using [the `keyof` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html#the-keyof-type-operator)).

And, for what it's worth, you don't need `T` to be a second generic type parameter in `foo2()`.  There's nowhere from which `T` is inferred, so it will just fall back to the [constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) of `Decoded<K>`, which means you can use `Decoded<K>` directly anywhere you would have used `T`:

```
function foo2<K extends EncodedType<Type>>(params: Record<K, string>) {
   // use DecodedType<K> in place of T anywhere in here, or in the return type
}
```

But you're really asking if there's any way to do it in the other direction, where `T` is the generic type parameter directly, as in `foo()`.

---

The answer to that seems to be "no, this is not possible".  You are asking the compiler to infer the generic type `T` from a value of type `Params<T>`, or `` { [P in T]: Record<`${P}Id`, string> }[T] ``, which is not straightforward at all.  If I were to try to do that myself I'd need to peer into your distributive object type and see that you're going to end up with... a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of `Record`s, each of which has a single key which is the string you want with `"Id"` appended to the end.  It's not *impossible* for me to do that, but it's not obvious.  And the compiler is hopelessly lost.

Indeed, even if you removed the union part it still wouldn't work:

```
type InferKey<T> = T extends Record<`${infer U}Id`, string> ? U : never;
type X = InferKey<{ FooId: "abc" }>
//   ^? type X = string
```

It's apparently too much to expect the compiler to [infer from template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html#inference-with-template-literals) if the template literal type inference site is indirect.

As evidence that template literal type inference is tricky, there's [microsoft/TypeScript#49839](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/49839), which is listed as "cursed?" because any cure might be worse than the disease.  This isn't exactly what's going on with your code, but it's similar in that the compiler loses track, fails to infer, and ends up falling back to a constraint which is not useful to you.

So, while it might be more annoying to you to write code like `foo2()` instead of `foo()`, it has the distinct advantage of being conducive to successful generic type argument inference.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&jsx=0&ts=5.3.3#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgdgMwgJwNIRAHgCoD4oC8U2UEAHsBHACYDOUAShAMYD2y1mABgCQDeAS0QooAVQC+MalwA0UWsGRCA5vgD8YqAC4ocCADcUAbgBQoSFAAahWMLQZMfKADFWrKToBEAQwBGzTyhxXBMAelCoSIA9DXNoayIFJThlIA)